# rails: protected method `around_validation' called for #<StateMachine::Machine:0xba3014ec>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to implement the state_machine gem, in my rails project, I installed the gem, then I added the column "state" to my account_entries model:

```
  def change
    add_column :account_entries, :state, :string
  end
```

Then in my account_entries model I added the state machine initial methon like this:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :submitted do

end
```

Then in my view I show the time entry state:

```
account_entry.state
```

But when I try to create an account_entry from my application I get this error:

```
protected method `around_validation' called for #<StateMachine::Machine:0xba3014ec>
```

It says it's in the line 4 of my account_entries controller, this is the line 4 of my account_entries controller.

```
e.account_entries.create(params.require(:account_entry).permit(:time, :account_id))
```

Is this a bug?  Or is this my problem?  How can I solve it?  What does the error message mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is [an open issue in state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/251). One fix which is listed there works around the issue by making the `around_validation` method public:

```
# config/initializers/state_machine_patch.rb
# See https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/251
module StateMachine
  module Integrations
     module ActiveModel
        public :around_validation
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok let me know if I understood, I have to create a file state_machine_patch.rb in config/initializers/ with that code?

Comment: Correct. As the issue is still open, this would be your best bet. If you get another error, [read this comment on the issue](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/251#issuecomment-32133267).

Comment: Use the forked [state_machines](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines) gem instead since this one is no longer supported. 
I know this is quite an old question but I just wanted to leave this here for in case someone else encounters the same problem.

Comment: Use gem 'state_machines-activerecord', that solves this problem